# SKCropNode doesn't display anything

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skcropnode

I can't get SKCropNode to cooperate. I've played with this for HOURS I've copied verbatim hackingwithswifts guide and the only difference being my image and it will not work. So then I dumbed it down for myself with the code below and it still doesn't work.

I've tried the guide directly from hacking with swift and it didn't work. I copied code directly from apple documentation that also didn't work. I've wasted wayyyy too much time on the simple task of cropping an image.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit
class ProcGenPlanet: SKScene{
//Background
//let background = SKSpriteNode()
var square = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redSquare")
square.size = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)
square.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
let cropNode = SKCropNode()
cropNode.maskNode = mask
cropNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
cropNode.addChild(square)
}
}
```

I am creating 1000x1000 red square. The whole image is red. Then I am trying to crop it to 100x100 with the following code but instead NOTHING shows up.

Comment: 1) delete all lines where you are setting `position`, 2) your mask should contain transparent (allows through) and non-transparent (filters) pixels, and 3) you need to add cropNode to the scene.

Comment: I ended up scratching all this code and copy and pasting the hacking with swift example and it worked. But I'm sure it wasn't working because I somehow didnt add cropNode to scene so I'd mark this as the right answer if it weren't a comment.